# LINQ query returns "collection has been modified" in asynchronous application

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I've just started diving into LINQ. Custom lists are being modified simultaneously (random functions add/modify/remove records). Having completed modifications IAsyncResult (or should I say EndInvoke) functions are trying to process results. I've built a different application trying to catch and eliminate faults causing these errors without any success. Adding `.ToList()` (which should create a hard copy of processed list) before `FindIndex` or in `Select`(Lambda) scope didn't do the trick, application kept on failing.

I assume that Select and FindIndex operations are iterating through `List<T>` and I don't like the idea to ignore new data in case it's just arrived (e.g. ignoring new inserts - building copy of data before processing or using locks). Is there a way to avoid it? If not, how should I PROPERLY build copy of my list which is to be processed?

None of the methods were lucky:

1)

```
int indx = customList.FindIndex(f => f.id == interestingId); //lambda
if (indx!=-1)
{
  ...do some work...
}
```

2)

```
var result = customList.Select(f => f.id == interestingId); //lambda
if (data!=null)
{
  ...do some work with item...
}
```

3)

```
var data = from s1 in customList 
           where s1.id == interestingId
           select s1.id;
if (data!=null) //linq
{
  ...do some work with data...
}
```

Exception rises near

```
f => f.id == interestingId
```

Questions are:

1. How should I PROPERLY extract data for read-only purpose in asynchronous application? (threadsafe topics?)
2. What approach should I use to modify/remove records from lists? This method doesn't seem to be working:

   ```
       int indx = customList.FindIndex(f => f.id > interestingId);
       if (indx != -1) customList.RemoveAt(indx);
              OR
       customList.RemoveAll(f => f.id > srn);
   ```

which are literally the same.

Any advices/opinions/criticism are warmly appreciated.

Comment: You should use [Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should use **lock** when you make changes to the collection.

```
List<CustomElement> customList = new List<CustomElement>();
lock (((ICollection)customLis).SyncRoot)
{
    customList.RemoveAll(f => f.id > srn); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @MarjanNikolovski, you should use a lock while updating your list and accessing it simultaneously.

My personal suggestion is to use [thread-safe collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for these purposes, to avoid the use of a lock and other possible multithreading issues. Indeed, `List<T>` is not a thread-safe collection (this is the reason of your error), as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=EqxWNWZGqlj):

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but
>   issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read.
>   To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write
>   operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads
>   for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

I think the best candidate, in your case, is the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) thread-safe collection.